# Angular html file can't find JS controller [Node.js/Angular]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

Here's the files/folders in my project all in the same folder.

Github Repo for the project: https://github.com/JohnsCurry/learnAngular
Just to prove they are all in the same directory. Sorry I don't have the package.json file. The only thing to install is express. I did `npm install --save express`. So I don't know why the package.json file didn't show up.

I've tried this same exact structure without a server running (Just static html and JS files client side only) and the 13.html file finds the controller13.js file just fine.  When i'm running Node.js it doesn't work.

My error:

> GET http://localhost:3000/controller13.js localhost/:8 angular.js:38
>   Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=mainApp&p1=Error%3…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

So it can't find the controller13.js file for some reason, and I'm assuming that's why I'm getting the `$injector` error.

13.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>AngularJS | Hands On!</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="controller13.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="">
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

controller13.js

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/page13.html'
  })
  .when('/helloUser', {
    templateUrl: '/hello13.html'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/13.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: You forgot confirm static folder. app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Comment: Thanks... I got a different error now, but that's a totally different thing I think. Now my problem is my Angular code is bad. Sorry for the noobie question.

Answer (score 1):

you are mixing Angular 1.3.14 and Angular-route 1.4.4. Fix up the version and see.